# No me cambia la variable

Tags: javascript, setinterval, onkey

Hola tengo este codigo

```js
var KeyD;
    setInterval(function(){
        if(KeyD){
            var tecla = KeyD;
            console.log(tecla);
        }
    },20);

    document.onkeydown = function(event){var KeyD = event;}
    document.onkeyup = function(){var KeyD;}
```

```css
 #lol{
  position:absolute;
  border:1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="lol">.</div>
```

El problema esta en que al realizar el evento onkeydown no me cambia  KeyD a event

Comment: ¿Te has dado cuenta que estás definiendo una variable local que se llama igual que la global en `var KeyD = event;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema que tienes es que estás asignando el valor del evento a una variable local por haberla definido como `var KeyD = event`.

Simplemente quitando `var` se asignará el valor del evento a la variable global y no se perderá su contenido tras la ejecución del evento.

```js
/* Variable global */
var KeyD;

setInterval(() => {
    if (KeyD) {
        var tecla = KeyD;
        console.log(tecla.key);
    }
}, 20);

/* Modificamos la variable global en vez de crear
  una local que se perderá tras su ejecución */
document.onkeydown = (event) => { KeyD = event; };
document.onkeyup = () => { KeyD = null; };
```

```css
#lol{
    position:absolute;
    border:1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="lol">.</div>
```

He usado el valor de [`KeyboardEvent.key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key), hay que tener en cuenta que [`keyCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) está obsoleto y podría dejar de ser soportado por los navegadores en cualquier momento.

Comment: Entonces remplazo keyCode por which?

Comment: Deberías reemplazar keyCode por key. En la respuesta está el enlace a la documentación.